# php shell_exec sudo on CENTOS 7

Tags: php, apache, centos, shell-exec

I've got an issue with shell_exec and sudo on centos 7.
The following line gives no output while executing from apache:

> $stat = shell_exec('sudo scripts/usb/hidusb-relay-cmd ID=HIUPS stat');

var_dump($stat); gives NULL

I have added the following lines using visudo:

> apache ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/scripts/usb/hidusb-relay-cmd
>
> Defaults!/var/www/html/scripts/usb/hidusb-relay-cmd !requiretty

In /var/log/secure I can read as follows:

> Jun  4 17:45:43 anhelli sudo:  apache : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/var/www/html ; USER=root ; COMMAND=scripts/usb/hidusb-relay-cmd ID=HIUPS stat

I tried su - apache and running sudo as above but it works fine.
Why I cant get the output of shell_exec, any ideas?

Many thanks for your help.
Best Regards
bzc0fq

Comment: `scripts/usb/hidusb-relay-cmd ID=HIUPS stat` Does this work in normal command line?

Comment: yes, it works fine when running as root. It works also from apache user command line as sudo. I tried also changing /etc/sudoers so that it gives sudo privs to all files run by apache user but it did not help.

Comment: Have you tried doing a 'ps aux | grep Apache' to make sure it's running as Apache and not dropping privileges?

Comment: I did something else, I put ls -al into shell_exec and is worked OK. Then I added sudo like this:  $stat = shell_exec('sudo ls -al'); and I got nothing in $stat... The same situation as before with hidusb command. I am not sure I set sudo privilages correctly... I put something like this in /etc/sudoers:  apache ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
Defaults!ALL !requiretty
It did not changed the situation. I still got NULL in $stat

Comment: I have found something. I have set SELinux to permissive mode and the script works fine I mean I got the shell_exec output as expected. I would rother try not disabling SELinux and find better sollution... any ideas how to investigate this further...?

Comment: I looked at /var/log/audit/audit.log and found some denials:type=AVC msg=audit(1465066548.250:389): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=2483 comm="hidusb-relay-cm" name="001" dev="devtmpfs" ino=1127 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:usb_device_t:s0 tclass=chr_file
type=AVC msg=audit(1465066548.250:389): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=2483 comm="hidusb-relay-cm" path="/dev/bus/usb/001/001" dev="devtmpfs" ino=1127 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:usb_device_t:s0 tclass=chr_file
Any idea what to do with this?

Comment: I tried to build policy package but I must have messed up something becouse it did not work in the end. what I have done was: grep denied /var/log/audit/audit.log  | audit2allow -M mysemanage then semodule -i mysemanage.pp and changed policy to tergeted. Unfortunatelly problem came back. Any hints on building pp?

Comment: I found an error in /var/log/httpd/error_log after enabling selinux. sudo: unable to execute scripts/usb/hidusb-relay-cmd: Permission denied when I disable selinux there are no errors, so this is selinux issue. Any help on this please?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved the problem. It was selinux policy blocking access to the hidusb-relay-cm file. The sollution was adding local security policies using commands:

> cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep denied | grep hidusb-relay-cm |
> audit2allow -M hidusb-relay-cm
>
> semodule -i hidusb-relay-cm.pp

I changed policy name every time I run audit2allow utility.
I had to run it 5 times until all denials have been 'serviced'.
I also had to set sebool on twice:

> setsebool -P httpd_mod_auth_pam on
>
> setsebool -P httpd_unified on

The catch was that I had to run command

> semodule -DB

to see hidden denials in /var/log/audit/audit.log
The above worked for me.